# Doubly linked list in C (printing)

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I've created doubly linked list and I managed to print it going forward from head to tail, however I`m having trouble in doing it backwards. I get segmentation fault in line "current = current->prev", I don't understand why.

```
current = head;

while (current) {
  printf("%p\t%s\t%d\n", current, current->name, current->age); 
  current = current->next;
}

current = current->prev;

while (current) {
  printf("%p\t%s\t%d\n", current, current->name, current->age); 
  current = current->prev;
}
```

I have found how to fix this problem:

```
current = head;

while (current) {
  printf("%p\t%s\t%d\n", current, current->name, current->age); 
  current = current->next;
}

current = head;
while (current->next) current = current->next;

while (current) {
  printf("%p\t%s\t%d\n", current, current->name, current->age); 
  current = current->prev;
}
```

However, I still don't understand why my method didn't work. I would thankful if somebody could explain this.

Comment: Hint: prefer `for(current = head; current;  current = current->next) {...}` loops. It saves you more than two lines. /style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you finish the loop traversing in a forward direction, `current` will be set to `NULL`, so using the line:

```
current = current->prev;
```

is *not* going to end well. You are not allowed to dereference `NULL`.

The reason your second code snippet works is because of this:

```
current = head;
while (current->next) current = current->next;
```

It leaves `current` pointing to the *last* item in the list rather than `NULL`.

Most doubly linked lists tend to have both a `head` *and* a `tail` and you would use the latter for a reverse scan.

If you *don't* have a `tail`, that second code snippet may *seem* like an acceptable way to find the end, though less efficiently than it would be *with* a `tail`.

However, it has one fatal flaw, which is that it will probably misbehave if the list is empty:

```
current = head;                 // current <- NULL
while (current->next)           // cannot dereference NULL
    current = current->next;
```

You would be better off with something like:

```
current = head;
if (current != NULL)
    while (current->next != NULL)
        current = current->next;
```

That will leave `current` set to `NULL` if the list is empty, or set to the address of the last item if it's not. That means your reverse loop will then work correctly:

```
while (current != NULL) {
    doSomethingWith (current);
    current = current->prev;
}
```

Comment: I do understand that after while cycle current will point to NULL but why it is wrong to use current = current->prev? Current would only point to the previous member, right?

Comment: @Evil0Teddy: no, `current` has, shall we say, "left the building". Once it gets set to NULL, it's no longer a pointer to something in the list so there's no item there that you can get the `prev` field for.

Comment: If you visualize that by drawing on a paper that would help. Current -> prev would point to prev, ONLY if you have a valid pointer in current. Once it becomes null, there is no valid list node in it, with a prev pointer. You first need pointer to a valid structure, in order to use any of its fields.

Comment: @Evil0Teddy: Just to amplify that: It doesn't "point to NULL" (get out of the habit of thinking that - it will confuse you, especially when you start working with pointers-to-pointers). Instead it *is* NULL. It doesn't point *anywhere* (at least, nowhere meaningful), so dereferencing it will not do anything good.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you traverse the list in forward direction to print it's elements the loop ends when `current == NULL` and then you try to dereference `current` immediately after that in

```
current = current->prev;
/*          ^ NULL */
```

Try this instead

```
current = head;
while (current->next) {
   printf("%p\t%s\t%d\n", current, current->name, current->age); 
   current = current->next;
}
printf("%p\t%s\t%d\n", current, current->name, current->age); 

while (current) {
   printf("%p\t%s\t%d\n", current, current->name, current->age); 
   current = current->prev;
}
```

notice that in your **fix** you essentially do that.